# Selenium Python: Can't click the button

Tags: python, selenium, button

Hope you are all safe!

My issue is pretty common, and I've seen tons of similar questions, though things like "wait/explicitly wait/wait until clickable etc" didn't work for me. I think I would like to ask for tailored solution for this problem :)

I try to scrape some data from here http://kuap.ru/banks/8012/balances/en (I use Russian language version of the website, but I think source must be pretty the same)

To do this, I have to choose appropriate data from drop-down list and then press button "Compare Data". However, I can't click that button.

[The button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GFxr.png)

My simple code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select[name = CurDate]').click()
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select[name = CurDate]'))
select.select_by_visible_text('01.01.2019')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BalanceTable"]/thead/tr[1]/th[3]/input').click()
```

The last row doesn't actually click. I've seen that many times the problem is in the path, and I tried several CSS paths - nothing worked. It looks like the same problem is here: when I try to get *.text* of the button it returns *' '*, whereas for other buttons it returns their actual text.

My main hypothesis is that the problem may be in this mysterious "Shadow content"
[(See a snapshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCvep.png)
I can't view it in Safari. I tried to access it via "...input//" (though it is a bit stupid, I know), but didn't manage to see it. I've read something about DOM etc... But it didn't really help (or I read badly)

So, any useful hints will be of a very great value! Already spent several hours on this very basic stuff :)

P.S. To make full disclosure - I'm super new to Python, trying to learn about data collection from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below xpath :

```
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn btn-default']"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Working code:**

```
driver.get('http://kuap.ru/banks/8012/balances/en')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='CurDate']"))
select.select_by_visible_text('01.01.2019')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn btn-default']"))).click()
```

[image]

**Another solution using java script ::**

```
element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn btn-default']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: @Gcube: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button from your end.

Comment: Hi Dipak, Thanks for swift reply. However, it didn't help :(
I'm pretty sure it must be safari vs chrome you use. Because what I get with your piece of code is pretty the same I got before - change in drop-down list (fine) but numbers don't change (i.e. button is not clicked).

Comment: Yes I have used chrome browser, What error are you getting also can you please check you zoom level ,  I have added another solution with java script please check it

Comment: Again thanks! 
1) First of all, JS solution worked. But for programming noob like me it is like a jump into another dimension :)
2) For Python solution: there is no error, actually. It works but nothing happens to the button
3) I used this to zoom:
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100)")
    But does it matter?

Anyway, thanks a lot, this helped. But if you have some time - I'm really curios why it didn't worked with the origianl code